# Is it good to define a function in a function python

Tags: python

Here is the code I wrote in a project.

Which one is a better one to write python?

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
    ....
    def parse_state(item):
        return re.sub('\[edit\]', '', item)
    uni_towns['State'] = uni_towns['State'].apply(parse_state)
    return uni_towns
```

Or:

```
def parse_state(item):
    return re.sub('\[edit\]', '', item)
def get_list_of_university_towns():
    ....
    uni_towns['State'] = uni_towns['State'].apply(parse_state)
    return uni_towns
```

This "parse_state(item)" function is only called once in "get_list_of_university_towns()" and will be never used again. Personally I think define it inside a function will be easier to understand. However, I barely see this kind of codes in other people's project.

So, how should I write this piece of code?

Comment: Or you could define a lambda function inline

Comment: This really depends on you use-case.  If you will find the function `parse_state` useful at other points of your code, then the second case makes more sense.

Comment: If you don't need `parse_state` anywhere else, I vote for defining it inside `get_list_of_university_towns` or using a lambda function.

Comment: They’re more or less the same in terms of cleanliness if `parse_state` is meaningful enough on its own (and that it doesn’t rely on locals of `get_list_of_university_towns` is one sign pointing to that). (The real change is to `item.replace('[edit]', '')`. )

Comment: Suppose **lambda** is not an option ( function is too complicated) and the function will only be called **once** .

Comment: What is `uni_towns['State']` that is has an `apply` method, rather than simply writing something like `uni_towns['State'] = re.sub('\[edit\]', '', uni_towns['State'])`?

Comment: @chepner uni_towns is a pandas DataFrame

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Is it Pythonic to write functions inside functions

Yes, it is. Actually, it is more Pythonic to do it inside than outside in order not to pollute the module namespace.

## How should I write this piece of code?

The option with the function definition inside the other function works. Another Pythonic way would be to use an anonymous lambda function:

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
    ....
    uni_towns['State'] = uni_towns['State'].apply(lambda item: re.sub('\[edit\]', '', item))
    return uni_towns
```

## Optimizing

As it has been suggested, and now that you said it is a panda's dataframe which means that the function will be called more than once, you should either compile the expresion or use `str.replace()` instead of `re.sub()`:

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
    ....
    uni_towns['State'] = uni_towns['State'].apply(lambda item: item.replace('[edit]', ''))
    return uni_towns
```

Comment: I disagree with the second part; whether a `lambda` expression is better than a named function here is somewhat a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @chepner Edited to give both options the same value. I try to avoid basing my answers on personal preferences but sometimes they slip in.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine. The first one is cleaner as you do not pollute module namespace with a name that is not used elsewhere.

And the first form should be slightly faster as `parse_state` is a local variable when it is called, especially important if it is used within a loop. There is no runtime cost to defining the function inside another function. At runtime, it is a simple assignment.

However, if it is used inside a loop, you should also compile the regular expression in the module scope:

```py
_state_re = re.compile('\[edit\]')
def get_list_of_university_towns():
    ...
    def parse_state(item):
        return _state_re.sub('', item)
    uni_towns['State'] = uni_towns['State'].apply(parse_state)
    return uni_towns
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Adirio's answer if a function is needed.

Alternatively, you could consider whether a function is really necessary if it's only used once.
If it is possible to iterate over uni_towns['State'], this would achieve the same and is in my opinion more readable:

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
    ....
    for state in uni_towns['State']:
        state = re.sub('\[edit\]', '', state)
    return uni_towns
```

Comment: You do not have information of what `uni_town['State']` is, you only know that it has an apply method that accepts a function as a parameter.

Comment: True, I'm assuming it's an array of strings, with the builtin iterable apply function

Comment: And by an array you are mining literally a panda's array aren't you? I think that is a assumption that should not be made without asking in a comment before.

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify that I am assuming iterating over uni_towns['State'] is a possibility.

Comment: Thanks! uni_towns is a pandas DataFrame, so it's better to use the apply method.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to create another function for what you are trying to achieve. Creating a function outside is better so that you can call it in other functions as well rather than limiting the use of it to only to where it is written.

Comment: If you want to do it without creating another function you would need more information about what `uni_town['State']` is. Creating a fucntion outside is NOT better, you are polluting the module namespace, he already said that it won't be called from anywhere else.

Comment: What i meant was either create a separate function or do the required changes inside the same function without creating another. Basically no need to have another function as i mentioned earlier.